# NRF52840 chip antenna design

Tags: antenna, ceramic

I am currently in the process of creating a custom PCB with a chip antenna. I have taken the schematic from the NRF9160-DK as a reference. I would use the same components, but leave out the coaxial socket.

My question is: How do I calculate the transmission line? I am familiar with the calculator in KiCad, but I don't know what to enter as length.

Where does the transmission line start and end? Theoretically, I would lay out the transmission line from C30 to C31, but there is still the F1 filter in between.

Why are other values taken for C29 and C30 than in the reference circuit of the NRF52840?

Reference circuit from NRF9160-DK:
[image]

Reference circuit from datasheet NRF52840:
[image]

Datasheet antenna: 2450AT18D0100 The antenna datasheet does not specify any values for a matching cicuit.

Comment: Janik Weis - Hi, In order to comply with the Stack Exchange [rule for referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question and add the *link* to the original source for each image which you included (and please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future). Please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. TY